# GreenDao как получить callback после совершения операции с бд?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dao

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, нужно реализовать взаимодействие приложения с бд,  решил использовать библиотеку GreenDao, успешно добавил её в проект, научился записывать и читать из базы, но не пойму, *как можно получить callback* после совершения операции? Например, после того, как добавили запись в таблицу, хочу отобразить это в списке. 
В описании библиотеки написано,что есть поддержка асинхронного взаимодействия с дб (асинхронные запросы к бд), и указан класс `AsyncOperationListener` для получения callbackов после выполнения действия. Документации по своему вопросу не нашёл. 
Возможно ли используя эту библиотеку получать эти колбэки, или самому что то реализовывать ( например, написать observer какой-нибудь).
И отдельный вопрос на счет шифрования бд. Т.е. естествено же что в открытом виде хранить нельзя, как это сделать? Использовать библиотеки? `SQLCipher` ?
p.s. очень жду комментов, т.к. такую задачу получил впервые)
Спасибо!

UPD: Задача, добавляем в бд много записей, это занимает n-секунд, после того, как узнать, в какой момент эти записи были добавлены?

Comment: Не совсем понял зачем вам callback на совершение операции. Если вы хотите обновить, скажем, ListView после записи, то почему не обновите адаптер? Если вам прям так нужно callback именно на завершение операции, то почему бы не реализовать логику записи в бд в обычном AsyncTask'e?

Comment: @Rishka вопрос в том, что в описании библиотеки сказано, что есть уже реализованный механизм оповещения , но не понятно, как им пользоваться